# Loading log4j in ContextListener

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to move from log4j 1.x to 2.x and I'm having some trouble. I was using slf4j/log4j1.2.x but am trying to get off the slf4j stuff and just use log4j.

I have a web application that uses two shared jars that have their own log4j configuration files. Previously I was able to load them using DOMConfigurator:

```
DOMConfigurator.configure(Loader.getResource(sContext.getInitParameter(CoreServicesListener.INIT_SYSLOGGING_FILE)));
```

Not sure how to do this anymore in log4j2. I've checked several resources on the web and nothing seems to be getting me to the right path. I'm hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to replace your custom `ServletContextListener` with the `log4j-web` module (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)).

The `log4j-web` module uses the servlet context parameter "log4jConfiguration", which accepts string interpolation. If for any reason you can not change the old parameter name, you can set the value of "log4jConfiguration" to `${web:initParam.old_param_name}` (cf. [Web Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#WebLookup)).

**Remark**: Log4j 1.x and 2.x configuration formats are incompatible. You need to convert the configuration files before migrating.

Comment: thank you! i realized that the config files had to be different after I renamed my custom logging.xml (it was under /config/logging.xml) to /log4j2.xml on the classpath. It's not what I wanted, but it works.

Comment: @KevinHuntly: if you are looking for a programmatic solution, you can use [`Configurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html) (assuming you are using Log4j2 Core as backend). Programmatic solutions are discouraged since they can break on a major version bump.